# GetResponse() in API call causes (400) Bad Request error

Tags: c#, request, httpwebresponse, webresponse, getresponse

I am very new to programming.

I'm setting up a loop that continuously send a POST request to a site through the REST API. The POST request works properly and the way I intend.

I would like to add functionality that requires the response from this post. However, every way of retrieving the response gives me an error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

As I debug line by line, it seems that the "GetResponse()" line causes this each time, and causes the program to break. If I remove this line, the program works properly and throws no errors.

Hoping someone can assist. Here is what I have written:

```
string URL= "https:.......";
HttpWebRequest apiCall = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(airWatchURL);
apiCall.Method = "POST";
apiCall.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, auth);
apiCall.Headers.Add("aw-tenant-code", apiKey);
apiCall.ContentType = "application/json";
apiCall.ContentLength = noBody.Length; //noBody = empty string
Stream c = apiCall.GetRequestStream();
Encoding d = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(c, d);
requestWriter.Write(noBody);
requestWriter.Close();

WebResponse apiResponse = apiCall.GetResponse(); //This line will return an error.
```

This will also return the same error:

```
HttpWebResponse apiResponse = apiCall.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

This will again return the same error:

```
string status;
using (HttpWebResponse response = apiCall.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    status = response.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

I just cant seem to correctly call the GetResponse Method.

Comment: You are not causing the error by your `GetResponse` line. The server is sending you an error. `GetResponse` is simply reacting to the error. The question is, what does the server not like about what you are sending it?

Comment: Since you're POSTing, let's see the code where you are setting the POST data.

Comment: Paul - Here is the rest of the request. This part appears to work properly, as the data is posted where I'd like. 

apiCall.Method = "POST";                        apiCall.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, auth);
apiCall.Headers.Add("aw-tenant-code", apiKey);
apiCall.ContentType = "application/json";
apiCall.ContentLength = noBody.Length; //noBody = empty string
Stream c = apiCall.GetRequestStream();
Encoding d = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(c, d);
requestWriter.Write(noBody);
requestWriter.Close();

Comment: `as the data is posted where I'd like` <-- where does it go? what evidence do you have that it goes anywhere correctly?

Comment: Just a guess here, but you're telling the server you're sending json but then sending an empty string.  Would sending valid but empty json like "{}" work?  I don't understand why you would do a POST and not send any data.

Comment: wal - it is posting information into a website. I have validated that the data posts exactly where I'd like it to go.

paul - For this post request, all variable data necessary for the post is in the URL itself.